# MY AVD is not showing ok option when we creat a new device

Tags: android

I just installed the Android Eclipse Plugin and the Android SDK from Google yesterday. I open the AVD Manager window by going to Window -> Android Virtual Device Manager. I then click "New" and am presented with the "Create new Android Virtual Device (AVD)" window. The problem is, I can't get the "OK" button to not be greyed out. I choose "Android 2.2  API level 8 " as the the taget

Comment: Have you filled in all of the required fields? Perhaps a screenshot of what you have done will help clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You must select at least one CPU/ABI from the dropdown when creating an AVD. If this option is disabled please install appropriate system image in your Android SDK Manager. Probably you can install ARM EABI v7a System Image. Also please don't forget to restart Eclipse..